# break outside loop error

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm new to python and I am receiving an error stating

> break outside loop

I know a break can only be used within a lopp but I actually have no idea when it determines when a loop finishes.

How can I solve this error by placing the break in the correct place (if that is what is causing the issue)?

code:

```
# see if we have an available date in this month
try:
    next_available_date = current_date.find_element_by_xpath("following::td[@data-handler='selectDay' and ancestor::div/@id='departureDateContainer']")
    print("Found an available date: {day} {month} {year}".format(day=next_available_date.text, month=month, year=year))
    next_available_date.click()
except NoSuchElementException:
# looping over until the next available date found
        while True:
# click next, if not found, select the next year
            try:
                calendar.find_element_by_class_name("ui-datepicker-next").click()
            except NoSuchElementException:
# select next year
                year = Select(calendar.find_element_by_class_name("ui-datepicker-year"))
                year.select_by_visible_text(str(int(year.first_selected_option.text) + 1))

# reporting current processed month and year
                month = Select(calendar.find_element_by_class_name("ui-datepicker-month")).first_selected_option.text
                year = Select(calendar.find_element_by_class_name("ui-datepicker-year")).first_selected_option.text
                print("Processing {month} {year}".format(month=month, year=year))

try:
    next_available_date = calendar.find_element_by_xpath(".//td[@data-handler='selectDay']")
    print("Found an available date: {day} {month} {year}".format(day=next_available_date.text, month=month, year=year))
    next_available_date.click()
    break
except NoSuchElementException:
    continue
```

Comment: The indentation determines the end of the loop.  Your third (final) `try` resets the indentation level, and is therefore outside the loop.

Comment: the break also determines the end of the loop, but must be within the loop indentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`break` in python is used inside a loop. It should be easy to locate the loop as python code need to properly indented. `break` in your code is outside of loop, it is in a try block. Similar is the case for continue.

I am not sure of the logic but this can be **fixed by bringing/indenting the following try block inside the `while` loop**

```
try:
    next_available_date = calendar.find_element_by_xpath(".//td[@data-handler='selectDay']")
    print("Found an available date: {day} {month} {year}".format(day=next_available_date.text, month=month, year=year))
    next_available_date.click()
    break  #this break is in the try block
except NoSuchElementException:
    continue
```